# Assigning to a variable by reference?

Tags: c#

Thanks to the kind folks who answered my previous question from a few days ago, I now know how to pass arguments by reference:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    int i = 0;
    Add(ref i, 100);
    // now i == 100
}

static void Add(ref int arg, int increment)
{
    arg += increment;
}
```

But is there a way for me not to just pass `i` by reference, but actually store its location in another variable? By that I mean use `i` like I did in my example; affecting the original instance, but in a way that's permanently linked and not leaving scope.

I vaguely know that I could use a pointer to determine the location in `unsafe` context but I was wondering if I could do this without any of that, or if it is just recommended to use the unsafe method.

Comment: Generally ref is a bad and smelly syntax. It always can be avoided. For example create class with variable i and implement method Add on it. Then you can reference class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C# 7 you can use [ref local and ref return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) to store an updateable reference to any field.

In this example I change the private field `_privateField` from 0 to 100 from outside `Foo`, the class in which it is defined, by returning it as a `ref int` and updating it by reference.

```
class Foo
{
    private int _privateField = 0;

    public ref int GetReference()
    {
        return ref _privateField;
    }

    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return _privateField.ToString();
    }

}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var referenceToPrivateField = foo.GetReference();
        referenceToPrivateField = 100;
        Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }
}
```

Prior to that, you'd have to store the value in a field contained in an object, and pass around a reference to the object instead.

In this example I change the value from 0 to 100 from outside `Foo`, even though it is stored (indirectly) in a field that is private inside the `Foo` instance.

```
class ValueTypeReference<T> where T : struct
{
    public  T Value { get; set; }
}

class Foo
{
    private ValueTypeReference<int> _privateField = new ValueTypeReference<int>{ Value = 0 };

    public ValueTypeReference<int> GetReference()
    {
        return _privateField;
    }

    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return _privateField.Value.ToString();
    }

}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var referenceToPrivateField = foo.GetReference();
        referenceToPrivateField.Value = 100;
        Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
100
```

Comment: Your `ref return` and `ref local` example won't work as expected. You should use `ref int referenceToPrivateField = ref foo.GetReference();` to make `referenceToPrivateField ` ref local.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I udnerstood you correctly, you want the variable to have *global scope*, which can be achieved by putting variable as class field/property:

```
class Program
{
  private static int _i;

  static void Main()
  {
    _i = 0;
    Add(100);
    // now _i == 100
  } 

  static void Add(int increment)
  {
    _i += 100;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, my goal would be something like this: You have two classes, a Map and a Location. The Locations have functions which affect a specific Map in some way. Because there are multiple Maps, you want to pass in only one specific Map in the Location constructor (a `ref`)so that the Location only affects that specific Map. How would you go about this?

Comment: @Cranberry48, Map is a reference type, int (as in your example) is a value type. They behave differently on passing them to functions. If you pass Map object to a function, inside which you will alter some property, you must not specify ref. If I did not understant your case, please give code lines.